Nextjs 14: requested resource was not found on this server
I am using next-auth for authentication in my project, which works fine in my local project but after deploying it on live i am getting error after entering email and password :requested resource was not found on this server. I am confused what is the issue exactly ? Can anyone help me out here.
My AUTH option location is : app/api/[...nextauth]/route.ts
I moved it to app/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts, after lokking at this : https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/6792
Din't worked for me.


import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import { LOGIN_USER, getUserData, logInUser } from "@/app/api/auth-api/routes";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [

    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "Password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        console.log("Reaching here", credentials);

        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        const data = { email: credentials?.email as string, password: credentials?.password as string };
        try {

          const response = await logInUser(data);



          if (response.data?.status === 200) {
            console.log("response ----- >", response.data?.success?.access, response.data?.success?.refresh);

            cookies().set("access", response.data?.success?.access, { path: "/" });
            cookies().set("refresh", response.data?.success?.refresh, { path: "/" });



            let user = await getUserData(response.data?.success?.access) as any;

            if (user?.data?.status === 200 || user?.data?.status === 201) {

              user = user.data;

              return { ...user?.success, ...response.data?.success, name: `${user?.success?.first_name} ${user?.success?.last_name}` };
            } else {
              throw new Error(user?.data?.error);
            }
            // } else if (response?.status === 422 || response?.status === 401 || response?.status === 500 || response?.status === 400) {
            //   console.log("response ----- > ERROR", response);

            //   throw new Error(response?.status === 400 && Array.isArray(response?.error?.non_field_errors) ? response?.error.non_field_errors[0] : response?.error);
          } else {

            throw new Error(response?.data?.error);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("error ----- >", error);

          throw new Error(error as any);
        }
      },
    }),

  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any, user: any }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any, token: any }) {
      session.user = token;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin", // Displays signin buttons
    // signOut: "/",
    error: "/not-found", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    // newUser: '/auth/register'
  },
};




export const logInUser = async (data: { email: string, password: string }) => {

    try {
        

        const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/${LOGIN_USER}`, data,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                httpsAgent: httpAgent,
            },
        );

        return response;

    } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            const axiosError = error as AxiosError<any>;
            if (axiosError.response) {
                // If there is a response from the server
                const { status, data } = axiosError.response;
                throw new Error(`${JSON.stringify(data.error[0])}`);
            } else {
                // If there is no response from the server
                throw new Error('API request failed with no response from the server');
            }
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }

};



const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/dashboard/`
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log("res", res);
        if (res?.ok) {
          router.push("/dashboard");
        } else if (!res?.ok) {
          toast.error("Login Failed", {
            position: "top-right",
            description: res?.error,
            action: {
              label: "Close",
              onClick: () => { },
            },
          });
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
      );


